# Extension theorems in a topological space

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

I have to prove some cases of extention problems one of them is :
If $X$ be a completely regular space and $E$ is a subspace of $X$ which consists of a closed set $F$ of $X$ and a point $p \in X \setminus F$,
if $g:E\to I$ denotes the continuous map defined by 
$$g(x)=\begin{cases} 0 &\text{ if } x=p\\
 1 & \text{ if } x \in F\end{cases}$$
then $g$ has an extension $f:X\to I$

Comment: This is basically the *definition* of being complete regularity. BTW, learn MathJax.

Comment: I am asking for how to prove the map g has extention map f and I will learn MathJax since that is my first time here

Comment: What is your definition of $X$ being completely regular? You can look at my edit for some ideas, and read the [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)..

Comment: I got it, thanks